# How can I find the reference manuals of the installed libraries?

Tags: libraries, shared-library, documentation

At the Software Center I installed a Reference manual of a library (*for example the GNU Scientific library (GLS)*) but I don't know how to find that reference manual.

[image: Software Center Screenshot]

I also tried:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep gsl
    libgslcblas.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0
    libgsl.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0
```

but I couldn't find it.

Comment: FYI you can find manuals for all default repo packages here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc files are usually in `/usr/share/doc/`.

To check it, you can use `apt-file`

```
apt-file list gsl-doc-pdf
```

or `dpkg` (only if the package is already installed)

```
dpkg -L gsl-doc-pdf
```

---

The output of the first is

```
$ apt-file list gsl-doc-pdf
gsl-doc-pdf: /usr/share/doc/gsl-doc-pdf/changelog.Debian.gz
gsl-doc-pdf: /usr/share/doc/gsl-doc-pdf/copyright
gsl-doc-pdf: /usr/share/doc/gsl-doc-pdf/gsl-ref.pdf.gz
```

So you can find it (as expected) in `/usr/share/doc/gsl-doc-pdf/`.

Comment: Thank you very much @dadexix86, I could find with your help. But is there a way find or organize all reference manuals? I would like have a tool that collect or gather like a help center or a simples link on the Software Center. Do you know something like that?

Comment: No, usually my reference manual is Google :)